# How do I reset my installation of Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Linux Subsystem for Windows on my machine. It works beautifully!

Since then, I've done unspeakable things to my install. Nothing works anymore. How do I start again from scratch?

Comment: This is no longer the recommended approach. PS C:\IaC> lxrun /uninstall
Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Windows Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After WSL 2 it's simple:

```
wsl --unregister Your_Ubuntu_distro
```

How to get distro name?

```
wsl --list
```

Per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands:

> **Caution**: Once unregistered, all data, settings, and software associated with that distribution will be permanently lost. Reinstalling from the store will install a clean copy of the distribution. For example, wsl --unregister Ubuntu would remove Ubuntu from the distributions available in WSL. Running wsl --list will reveal that it is no longer listed.

You may want to backup your home directory and other data prior to unregistering the distro.

Comment: Only this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 57):

You can reset Ubuntu from settings, just find it in the start menu, right-click to go to `App settings`, then press the `reset` button.

[image: find ubuntu in start]

[image: reset from settings]

Comment: Damn.. didn't expect it would be that straightforward!

Comment: that ends in: `Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/HCS/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira In this case I would try to Repair the whole installation or even uninstall and reinstall. Sorry.

Answer (score 23):

Open Command Prompt (AKA `cmd.exe`), and type `lxrun /uninstall`. That should wipe your Ubuntu image.

Once this is done, you can reinstall with `lxrun /install`.

References:

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/22/fun-with-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Comment: This would have to be run in the Windows `cmd.exe` shell, right?

Comment: Yup. I've edited to clarify.

Answer (score 10):

With the new distro-specific store apps, [for example](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/2385#issuecomment-338759719):

```
C:\> ubuntu /?
Launches or configures a linux distribution.

Usage:
    <no args>
      - Launches the distro's default behavior. By default, this launches your default shell.

...

    clean
      - Uninstalls the distro. The appx remains on your machine. This can be
        useful for "factory resetting" your instance. This removes the linux
        filesystem from the disk, but not the app from your PC, so you don't
        need to redownload the entire tar.gz again.
```

So, `ubuntu clean` should be enough.

If `ubuntu clean` fails, then you'll have to uninstall the app from the store and reinstall it. See [WSL #2387](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2387#issuecomment-319748890).

Comment: The `ubuntu clean` flag has been removed from the app.

Answer (score 0):

launch -> cmd /d

> ubuntu config --default-user root

launch -> C:\Windows\System32\bash

> passwd your_username
>    set new_password and confirm new_password
>   close the bash

back into cmd /d

> ubuntu config --default-user your_username

Launch the bash and fell free to use the new_password
 for your_username when needed 
(like for a "sudo apt-get install gcc")

Comment: This helped me resetting my lost password. Instead of doing the complete reinstallation or cleaning, I just did a password reset. Thanks!