# I accidentally moved /usr/bin on wsl and now I can't open a new terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to move a binary from my `/usr/bin` to my home directory on ubuntu WSL so I accidentally ran

```bash
sudo mv /usr/bin ~
```

Now I can't even open a new ubuntu terminal to undo the move.

I tried undoing the move from Windows by running:

```
wsl -e /home/<username>/usr/bin/sudo /home/<username>/usr/bin/mv /home/<username>/usr/bin /usr/bin
```

but I can't run any ubuntu commands from the `wsl` command

Is there a way to undo the move or do I have to reinstall the WSL distro?

Comment: You could try mounting the `ext4.vhdx` in a virtual machine and then maybe try to move the directory back to its original location.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380253/where-is-wsl-located-on-my-computer for the location of the file.  However, it might be easier to repair / reinstall WSL https://askubuntu.com/questions/761360/how-do-i-reset-my-installation-of-ubuntu-on-windows